# How Google determines which piece of content to be shown in the search result?

Tags: html, search, google-search

The Google search result usually contains a title and a piece of content from the indexed html. I can understand how title is extracted but does anyone know how Google determine which part of content to be shown?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/15974/1253

Answer (score 0):

Google uses several different algorithms to decide what to display in the search result snippet, so there's no way to define what will show 100% of the time. Google does appear to rely heavily on the "description" meta field, so what you put there is often a good indication of what will appear in the snippet, but once again, it's not a sure thing.